# How is Instagram detecting me and blocking me each and every time I try to create a new account through different medium?

Tags: ip, web

I have two Instagram accounts, one is mine **(Account A)** and the other **(Account B)** is for random images with my pets and a lot of other stuff.

Account B is private and has been from start, recently I want some of my close friends to have access to it, the only way they can access is if they follow me, but to follow, one would need to create an Instagram account. Now it is a simple solution, but not all my friends who I want to share this account with are not so interested in Instagram, so I decided to create a Gmail account and use that to create an Instagram account.

So I went to Gmail to create an email account, I did successfully. After that, I tried to open Instagram in a new Chrome browser in which I had previously logged in with my previous two accounts. Everything was going smoothly, but in the very end, after creation, a message comes stating there was an error. I googled this error and it comes out that Instagram blocked this new account as it recognised I have multiple accounts.

So what I tried to do is, repeat the steps from a new incognito mode browser, but the same error came.

Now for the third trial, Google this time asked for a mobile number in order to successfully create, nothing worked to skip it, new browser, clearing history/cache, trying through Opera browser with inbuilt VPN.

So I tried creating a Gmail account from my mobile with cell network, I succeeded in creating a Gmail account, but when I tried the same with Instagram in the phone itself I received the same blocked error message.

In the end after creating 4 more Gmail accounts through use of two different cell phones with two separate network internet, and by entering my phone number after there was no other option I was still blocked from Instagram for each try I did with different email ids.

I tried with Instagram in both phones with different cell networks, when connected in WiFi, through Opera inbuilt VPN, tried in MacBook and a Windows PC, and was very curious what is the one thing that is being used to recognise me and block me, what could it be.

I would appreciate if anyone can share their thoughts on how Instagram was able to detect that I was creating multiple accounts.

Also if anyway I can skip past the blockage for new Instagram account creation (although this is not my motive for this question but is very much appreciated).

Comment: are you using the same app for each account?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you ? Same app as in?
I tried to create new account in the instagram app, website in pc and mac

Comment: You might want to make that clear and tell Dmitry in his answer below

Comment: But that is already stated in my question in the last third paragraph.

Comment: It's lost a little bit. If the answer below is potentially an answer, then you *are* using the same app for the different accounts .

Comment: Any idea to check why my question might have been down voted, is it not apt for this community?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the same app, I mean the app is instagram, I am trying to create in app which had my previous account, also where no account was ever logged in, in web site clearing up all cookies/history, in both mac and pc.

Comment: Why is it a problem to create multiple accounts? Are you banned? Even the offficial app seems to allow [up to 5 accounts](https://help.instagram.com/1682672155283228)

Comment: I don't know the problem, I have had 2 accounts before this, not sure, at the very end when the account is created I get message popup that account is blocked.
All the email ids i have used are blocked in Instagram so i cannot use them to try again, when I try to use it, it gives error that the email id is already in use.

Answer (score 7):

Instagram app sends the device id to its servers. So your devices are already known to them. Your best way would be:

- A new device
- A new email provider
- Never connect to your wi-fi on this new device before registering

In other words, your new identity should not share even a single bit of the old identity.

Comment: oh didnt think about the device ID, that might be it, was clueless what can be the ways they detecting me.Cool.